# Can't change input language in any java application on windows

Tags: java, windows

I' m trying to switch windows input language by ALT+SHIFT from Russian to English but it doesn't in java applications. In windows it works fine but when I switch by ALT+TAB to one of java applications it doesn't work. To fix it I have to restart application, for example Itellij IDEA. But after some time it appears again. Can Anybody describe how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with "But after some time it appears again."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the default language is decided at start-up, as you experienced. This allows to override the default language using some command line arguments.

I'm afraid, this is how it is. You will have to restart the application to get the changed default language from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your java app keyboard preferences if it has its own shortcut-function bound to the ALT+SHIFT.
It may be so for IntelliJ IDEA.